# Is there any simple method for assigning values from inside to list to a model?

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 models like this

```
public class ModelA
{
 public string Name{get;set;}
 public string Value{get;set;}
}

public class B
{
 public List<ModelA>Items{get;set;}
}
```

The below input will be deserialized onto *class B*

```
{
  "Items":[
    {
      "Name":"Food Name"
      "Value":"Fries"
    },
    {
      "Name":"Weapon Name"
      "Value":"Gun"
    },
    {
      "Name":"Vehicle Name"
      "Value":"Car"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have another third model like below

```
public class ModelValues
{
 public string FoodName{get;set;}
 public string WeaponName{get;set;}
 public string VehicleName{get;set;}
}
```

I want to add the corresponding values of *model A* onto *ModelValues* class, like the value of *FoodName* property should get as Fries. Is there any simple way to assign the values of that *class A* to *ModelValues*.
i know that we can use something like

```
public void AssignValues(B products)
{
 ModelValues values=new ModelValues();
 values.FoodName=products.Find(x=>x.Name=="Food Name").Value;
 values.WeaponName=products.Find(x=>x.Name=="Weapon Name").Value;
}
```

In actual implementation since the items in *ModelValues* and the input will large i would like to avoid such line by line assigning of values. is there any ways to get this done with just few lines of code

Comment: You can try to use [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/) library and create a mapping configuration between types

Comment: You can use automapper. or, for fun, you can do your own thing. Lets say, declare `MappingPropertyAttribute`. Then on all your models you can list all the names to which your property maps - `MappingProperty("prop1", "prop2")`. Then have the extension for any model like `model1.HydrateTo(model2)`. And your code will populate properties that match name and data type. Or you can even try converting some data types.

Comment: Can you change json data for example ```Food Name``` to ```FoodName``` ?

Comment: SInce `B` is intended to be used as a lookup, make it a `Dictionary<Tkey,TValue>` to make the lookup faster and more natural.

Comment: @Saeed Esmaeelinejad changing json data is not possible as i'm taking it from an external source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes a list iteration for 3 times. This code only ones

```
var items = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(json);
var values = AssignValues(items);

public ModelValues AssignValues(B products)
{
    ModelValues values = new ModelValues();
    foreach (var item in products.Items)
    {
        if (item.Name == "Food Name") values.FoodName = item.Value;
        else if (item.Name == "Weapon Name") values.WeaponName = item.Value;
        else values.VehicleName = item.Value;
    }
    return values;
}
```

I don't think that is a good idea, but you can use reflections to do the same

```
public ModelValues AssignValues(B products)
{
   var dict=products.Items.ToDictionary(i => i.Name, i=> i.Value );

   var values = new ModelValues();
    var properties = values.GetType().GetProperties();
    
    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
         var name=prop.Name.Replace("Name"," Name");
         prop.SetValue(values,dict[name] );
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: the issue with this code is that this code will get much larger as my items in ModelValues Model and the input increases. i'll have to a lot of if conditions with larger data. so i'm looking for something to optimize this code a bit.

Comment: @ANK Your code makes a list iteration for 3 times. This code only ones

Comment: that's true. Is there any way for avoiding the if conditions? it's just that when the items in my classes increases then I'll have to put a lot of if conditions,which is something i would like to avoid if possible

Comment: @ANK if condition is quite fast and simple and doesnt take mach resources. Linq will convert code to foreach loops too. So better to use loops ifrom the start. But if you think about using mapper, then you should know that mapper using reflections  and your code will be thousand times more slow.

Comment: @ANK: It's hard to imagine why you need this design. You're going to keep adding properties to `ModelValues` as it grows. Isn't a collection a better approach to this? A `Dictionary<>` maybe?

Comment: @JonathanWood I am sorry but I don't see what I can gain. IMHO a list is  better then a dictionary in this case. Now I am iterating the list , if I use a dictionary I will have to iterate list of dictionary values. What is the difference?

Comment: @Serge: I was directing my comment to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

I would question your current approach. When you could end up adding any number of properties, a collection might be a better choice. Perhaps even a dictionary.

However, the following method will copy the values the way you want. It's not the fastest way to do this. But it will continue to work even when you add additional names and properties.

```
void Convert(B items, ModelValues values)
{
    Type type = typeof(ModelValues);
    
    foreach (ModelA item in items.Items)
    {
        string name = item.Name.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
        PropertyInfo info = type.GetProperty(name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (info != null)
            info.SetValue(values, item.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: It could have some sense if ModelValues were a dynamic object with unlimited quantity of properties that are unknown yet. But for 3 properties  a concrete code will be much more effective. You could save several mins for 2 lines code less, but it is not about this. OP lost the whole day already, He could create a concrete, very effective code for a hundred properties during this time

Comment: @Serge: Yes, but he said the number of properties could get much larger. For a single method that handles any number of properties, this approach would work. Personally, I would review the design and consider another approach.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many thousand properties you have, the concrete code is always more effective. You need a dynamic code only if you don't have any alternative sinceyou don't know the name of  the properties. But as I understand, ModelValues properties are always known. A compiler always translates the dynamic properties to the concrete ones. You can only save on the time writing the code, but after this you will lost more during runtime.

Comment: @Serge: I don't think my approach is the most efficient, but it will *always* work as properties are added. It doesn't need to be kept current. A lot of libraries use reflection, just like the `JsonConvert` call in your example. Yes, the `ModelValues` properties would be known. But it still requires someone to keep it current every time new values are added. Therefore, it is more error prone. I don't understand why you are so against this approach. Are you equally concerned about `JsonConvert` using reflection like this?

Comment: Yes, I  am agree, I could use parse instead of convert. I used it only  because OP uses it and he already created classes for this. But a typed object is always better if it is created already by OP.

Answer (score 2):

Another one variation of a Newtonsoft.Json usage:

```
public class ModelValues
{
    [JsonProperty("Food Name")]
    public string FoodName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Weapon Name")]
    public string WeaponName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Vehicle Name")]
    public string VehicleName { get; set; }
}

var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(json)
                       .Items
                       .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.Value);

JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(items);
var values = obj.ToObject<ModelValues>();
```

Or with no changes to ModelValues:

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<B>(json)
                       .Items
                       .ToDictionary(x => x.Name.Replace(" ", ""), x => x.Value);

JObject obj = JObject.FromObject(items);
var values = obj.ToObject<ModelValues>();
```

Comment: This assumes he can serialize from JSON directly to the `ModelValues` class. I didn't see where he said that.